# How can I avoid Building Solution (Solution.exe) everytime I run debugging?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Run to Debug solution

Message:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target [path] Solution.exe is missing. Please build the project can retry, or set the outputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

no choice to rebuild the whole solution again and again.

Comment: Solution and project are two different things. An exe comes from a project, not a solution. You don't need to build the solution when you debug your exe - only the exe project and its project references, and only when those projects have been modified.

Comment: I meant to project. when I run code for testing, it runs last build exe instead of current code. so I have to rebuild the project, again and again, every time I run code for testing.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/135634/362216)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

- Please ensure the output path(Project -> Properties -> Build ->
  Output path) of project is correct .
- Change menu to Build -> Configuration Manager, and then check if your
  main/entry project has checked Build. If not, please check it.
- Change menu to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run
  Theres a list under "On Run, when projects are out of date:" Select:
  "Always Build"->Save it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your output Path...
e.g **Project>Properties>Build>Output Path..**

Make sure it's correctly set..